# Correct way to use pos_tagger option in gensim + keywords extraction

Tags: keyword, gensim, pos-tagger, summarization

While using "[keywords()](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/8766edcd8e4baf3cfa08cdc22bb25cb9f2e0b55f/gensim/summarization/keywords.py#L200)" in summarization/keywords.py file, I am getting the same set of tags, no matter what value I choose for pos_tagger=['NN'], ['JJ'] or ['NN','JJ']

```
from gensim.summarization import keywords
import requests

url='https://www.nytimes.com/2018/05/16/opinion/ramadan-spirit-america.html'
text = requests.get(url).text

print keywords(text,words=15,pos_filter=('NN'),lemmatize=True,scores=True)
print keywords(text,words=15,pos_filter('NN','JJ'),lemmatize=True,scores=True)
print keywords(text,words=15,pos_filter=('JJ'),lemmatize=True,scores=True)
```

Expected Results

If  I am giving pos_filter as 'NN', only nouns should come as tags, however, tags like "started", "looking" are also coming as output.
Similarly, there is no difference in the output irresepective of pos_filter='NN', pos_filter='NN','JJ', pos_filter='JJ'

**What is the correct way of using pos_filter to reflect appropriate output?**

Actual Results

student:0.20870111939889552, muslims:0.18960896637225794, americans:0.18895097005190414, ramadan:0.17605599898176202, month:0.12130699512494893, started:0.11817668681654464, community:0.11691583075245701, places:0.1117677772315554, spirituality:0.103727092629442, car:0.09988305780275739, white:0.09747271853405554, trump:0.09747271853405551, looking:0.09538360210000996, president:0.09538360210000986, black:0.0920316444206821

student:0.2087011193988958, muslims:0.18960896637225758, americans:0.1889509700519042, ramadan:0.17605599898176225, month:0.12130699512494901, started:0.11817668681654461, community:0.11691583075245732, places:0.11176777723155559, spirituality:0.10372709262944187, car:0.099883057802757, trump:0.09747271853405544, white:0.09747271853405512, president:0.0953836021000099, looking:0.09538360210000954, black:0.09203164442068222

student:0.20870111939889593, muslims:0.1896089663722575, americans:0.1889509700519037, ramadan:0.17605599898176255, month:0.1213069951249494, started:0.11817668681654483, community:0.11691583075245665, places:0.11176777723155547, spirituality:0.10372709262944207, car:0.09988305780275722, white:0.09747271853405541, trump:0.09747271853405526, looking:0.09538360210000975, president:0.0953836021000096, black:0.09203164442068222